# Looking for recommendation

Tags: sql-server, powershell, automation, ole-automation

I am a non IT background, my recent projects uses PowerShell for a lot of SQL Server administration. I would like to start from absolute zero, and learn to use and code the Windows PowerShell as it was meant to be used. I am looking for a good book for beginners or other materials? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these article series on [SQLServerCentral.com](http://SQLServerCentral.com):

[Stairway to Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SMO/140966/)

[Stairway to SQL PowerShell](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/90381/)

These are a series of articles that provide great foundational skills right through to some advanced concepts and practises with specific focus on SQL Server and SMO.

Comment: thx, I really appreciate your response

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @HandyD for SQL Powershell.

Above that I will like to point one more source for Powershell learning [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/powershell/index.htm). This source coveres basics of Windows Powershell.

Now, first let's make one thing clear that Windows Powershell and SQL Powershell both are different.

SQLNeeds SQLPS installed as component. Similarly windows needs newer version of Powershell tools installed.

Note: Powershell have some version specific commands which may not be supported on older version in same way in current version. So check version of PS installed each time before starting on new machine. Latest is version 6 of Powershell [source: How to install Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell?view=powershell-6)

I hope this helps.